# Suggestion: clearer demarcation between jobs on CV

Tags: feature-request, jobs, cv

The format of work history on the CV is:

```
Title (Bold)
Tags
Description
```

Thing is, the tags act as more of a break in the flow than anything else. One could thing that what's between the tags is one job. I'd suggest a better demarcation. Perhaps a line between jobs, alternate shading or something similar.